# insert average month values in to another table but present month average values should prevet to pass to table

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works well. I want to prevent this month averages pass to avg_month_val1 how can i do it.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1`  ( `year` , `month` ,  
                                `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , `rainfall` , 
                                `max_temp` , `min_temp` ) 
SELECT year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year, 
       month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
       round(avg(evep),2),
       round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
       round(sum(rainfall),2),
       round(AVG(max_temp),2),
       round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM reg_data3
GROUP BY year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
         month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
ORDER BY 1 Desc;
```

Comment: I want to prevent this month averages pass to avg_month_val1..No understand

Comment: @Mihai in reg_data3 average values should not be enter to avg_month_val1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this does what you intent:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1`  ( `year` , `month` ,  
                                `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , `rainfall` , 
                                `max_temp` , `min_temp` ) 
SELECT year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year, 
       month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
       round(avg(evep),2),
       round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
       round(sum(rainfall),2),
       round(AVG(max_temp),2),
       round(avg(min_temp),2) 
FROM reg_data3
GROUP BY year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
         month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
HAVING (year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) <> year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     OR month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) <> month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) )
ORDER BY 1 Desc;
```